# How to change metadata Language in Google native document

Tags: google-drive-api

I can create native Google documents to Google Drive using API Drive 2.0.

But, I cant change the language body document. I think that TargetLanguage and SourceLanguage properties has other goals and they hasnt allow values in SDK reference.

For example, the default language to Google natives documents is "English". I want change by API to "Dutch" or "French".

This option is possible by Google Drive Interface: File > Language > [Choose your language].

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

The `targetLanguage` and `sourceLanguage` parameter of the Google Drive API can't be used to change the Google Document setting `File > Language > [Choose your language]`

`File > Language > [Choose your language]` changes the language of the integrated spell check in Google Documents whereas `targetLanguage` and `sourceLanguage` are there for translation of the file's content.

There is unfortunately no way to change the `File > Language > [Choose your language]` using the Drive API right now.