# Set the default language of Google document while file creation with Google DRIVE API

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-api-java-client

I can create files on Google Drive and the language is automatically set for me while using drive.google.com.

But I am having issues while creating files using Google Drive API via my application.(google-api-services-drive-v2-rev192-1.20.0.jar)

The default language of the document is not set.
This is causing issues with the voice typing being grayed out.

[image: Voice typing grayed out when the default language is not set]

Here is how I createFile in my application:

```
    public static File createFile(Car car) {
    System.out.println("CREATING FILE");
    try {

        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle("Document for " + car.getCar_name()
                + ".docx");

        body.setMimeType(GOOGLE_DOCOCUMENT_MIME_TYPE);
        body.setEditable(true);
        

       
        Permission ownership = getOwnerShipPermission();
        Permission unlockedFile = getUnlockedFilePermission();
        java.io.File fileContent = null;
        fileContent = CarServiceReportTemplateFactory.createCarServiceReportTemplateFile(car);
        
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(MS_WORD_DOCUMENT_MIME_TYPE, fileContent);
        File file = driveservice.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
        String fildid = file.getId();
        driveservice.permissions().insert(fildid, unlockedFile).execute();
        fileContent.delete();
        return file;
        
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I did have a look at [the drive api file category](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/) but I cannot find anything related to setting default language.

Interestingly, when I execute the ["Try it" simulator](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), the generated file seems to have a  language setup by default.
However, when I try it in my application, the language isn't set up by default...Hence the voice typing is grayed out.
This is what I have tried:

```
  String timedTextLanguage = "English (United Kingdom)";
           
  File file = driveservice.files().insert(body, mediaContent).setTimedTextLanguage(timedTextLanguage).execute();
```

Comment: I have noticed the drive client jar file has a newer version.
Could it be this?

Comment: If you check the v2 version of the Google Drive API. The only option that can change the language of a file is by using [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) method, this method has an optional parameter `timedTextLanguage` that set the language of the text. Try this parameter if it can help you. For more information, check also this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106138).

Comment: Hi Kendi, THank you for your help.
I did try the timedTextlanguage with no luck. Can i basically pass "English" as a string parameter?

Comment: I tried to pass en-GB, English, english, en as a parameter & I am still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Microsoft Word document causing these issues.
But I still don't know why the language isn't set as it is uploaded to Google Drive.