# How do I set the language of a Google Slide Presentation via API?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

I need to change the language of a google slide presentation.

To produce this presentation, I am using the Google Drive API & Google Slide API (nugets)

I am copying a presentation in English, then I insert text in it.

The new presentation should not be English, but instead French, Italian, ...

My current code looks like:

```
var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
   HttpClientInitializer = GetCredentials(),
   ApplicationName = ApplicationName
});
var newFile = new File
{
 Name = "new presentation",
};
// template is the initial presentation
var duplicatedFile = driveService.Files.Copy(newFile, template.Id).Execute();

var presentation = slideService.Presentations.Get(duplicatedFile.Id).Execute();
// setting the presentation here does not work :(
x.Locale = "fr";
// do the presentation changes
```

Do you know how to change the presentation's language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change metadata Language in Google native document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106138/how-to-change-metadata-language-in-google-native-document)

Comment: As what @Kos has shared, it seems like there's no option via the API to change the Google Slides presentation's language. However, there are alternative that you can try to consider checking. [Translate add-on for Google Slides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/slides/quickstart/translate)  
 _(however, this is done via Apps Script on Google Slides)_ & [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/overview) _(you can integrate this API to your existing C# project but this is a paid Google API)_

Comment: Thank you @kos. I believe this is the case indeed: not possible :(

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible via the API. Only via the UI.

See also [How to change metadata Language in Google native document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106138/how-to-change-metadata-language-in-google-native-document) for a more complete answer